# Node.js error: "Unexpected token ;" while on node-webkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I was trying to follow [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-html5-desktop-apps-with-node-webkit--net-36296) tutorial for making a simple text editor on node-webkit, but when i got to the part of wiring the modules I get this error:

```
Uncaught node.js Error 

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:69:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:470:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:352:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:360:17)
    at require (module.js:376:17)
    at window.require (eval at undefined, <anonymous>:1:112)
    at eval (file:///Users/Gonzo/Documents/node-webkit-v0.9.2-osx-ia32/js/main.js:1:12)
```

This is the main.js code taht seems to have the error:

```
var file = require('file.js');

console.log(file.open, file.save);
```

#### Edit

This is `file.js`

```
var fs = require('fs');
function File() {
    function open(path, document) {
        function open(path, document) {
            fs.readFile(path, 'utf-8', function (error, contents) {
                document.getElementById('editor').value = contents;
            });
        }
    }
    function save(path, document) {
        function save(path, document) {
            var text = document.getElementById('editor').value;
            fs.writeFile(path, text);
        }
    }
    this.open = open;
    this.save = save;
}
module.exports = new File;
```

Comment: What is in `file.js`? That is what is being parsed and throwing.

Comment: this is what is in file.js var fs = require('fs');
 
function File() {
    function open(path, document) {
         function open(path, document) {
    fs.readFile(path, 'utf-8', function (error, contents) {
        document.getElementById('editor').value = contents;
    });
}
    }
     
    function save(path, document) {
         function save(path, document) {
    var text = document.getElementById('editor').value;
    fs.writeFile(path, text);
}
    }
     
    this.open = open;
    this.save = save;
}
 
module.exports = new File;

Answer (score 0):

May be it is not **file.js's** fault.

I build a simple project and it works with your code.

Here is the project structure.BTW, index.js is all your code.

```
Project
|-- index.html
|-- package.json
|-- node_modules
      |--File
         |--index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file:///Users/Gonzo/Documents/node-webkit-v0.9.2-osx-ia32/js/main.js:1:12
```

Check out your `main.js` file.